# Is HTML5 application caching relevant?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a 2010 [tutorial by htmlrocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

I added app cache to my app and noticed FireFox started asking for my permission to store data.

This made me notice that other big sites like Facebook and Twitter do no use HTML5 Application Cache.  In fact, I can't think of another site that has asked me for permission to store data.  I'm guessing that this is because other sites do not use it.

Because it has been around so long I'm wondering if it is relevant or not ever really going to fly?

Here is the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=app%20ca).

**Update:**

Removed from my app.

Comment: The sites have not enabled it, because in my opinion it is a turn off to show users the messages by browsers like share your location, allow offline data et-al

Comment: On the other hand, if your users are explicitly asking for an "offline mode" feature to your web application, they probably will not mind the messages (or will whitelist your application to begin with if possible). *(Disclaimer: I personally look forward to using this technology in a future project, as we expect some of our customers to require this when "on the field".)*